# Ubuntu 21.04 Bluetooth Toggle Not Working Even After Switching it on

Tags: bluetooth

Now Ubuntu 21.04 is released and almost every dev has tried it.
But, there is one problem many people faced is that bluetooth is not turning on. Even toggle shows on it appears that bluetooth is off and unusable.
Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't turns on even after this command then first toggle your bluetooth on then try this command. I tried myself this way. It is working all the time.

sudo service bluetooth restart

Comment: It is absolutely valid to answer you own question on StackOverflow, but please [edit] your question to only a question and officially answer it afterwards

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Okay bro. next time I will be sure about it.

Answer (score 3):

I came to a solution to turn the blutooth on.

Just type this command in your terminal.

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

This turned on my bluetooth instantly.
I rechecked it and found that you must turn your toggle on before you use this command else it will not work.
Thanks

Comment: I use `systemctl restart bluetooth`, but I guess it does the same thing. Unfortunately, the bluetooth toggle just doesn't work in 21.04; I remember it worked in 20.04.